# Sitecore 6.6 publishing error: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, publishing

We have upgraded to Sitecore 6.6 and are receiving the following error intermittently during publishing. What could be causing this? It happens during publishing an item for the first time to the web / content delivery database (which is mirrored), whether using the smart-publish or republish option.

ETA: This problem *seems* to possibly be tied to publishing duplicated items, i.e. ones created by right-clicking on an existing item and choosing the "Duplicate" menu option.

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Exception
Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'. The duplicate key value is (aeff8886-e15a-45e6-8120-39777258380c).
The statement has been terminated.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Execute>b__14()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.CreateItem(ID itemID, String itemName, ID templateID, ItemDefinition parent, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.CreateItem(ID itemID, String itemName, ID templateID, ItemDefinition parent, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.CreateItemCommand.Execute(ID itemId, String itemName, ID templateId, Item destination)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.CreateItemCommand.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.CreateItem(String itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersion(Item sourceVersion)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.ExecuteAction(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.Publish()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.DataException
Message: Error executing SQL command: INSERT INTO [Items] (
                        [ID], [Name], [TemplateID], [MasterID], [ParentID], [Created], [Updated]
                       )
                       VALUES(
                        @itemID, @itemName, @templateID, @branchId, @parentID, @now, @now
                       )

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Items' with unique index 'ndxID'. The duplicate key value is (aeff8886-e15a-45e6-8120-39777258380c).
The statement has been terminated.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Duplicating an Item will generate a new GUID for it, so the publish seems to think the Item does not exist in your Web database when in fact it does. Is it a clean Web db? Can you switch to that database and check if it exists there in the Content Editor?

Comment: What version did you upgrade from? Is it possible that you have not run the provided sql scripts during the upgrade process? See this link: http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Update/6_6_0_rev_120918/Upgrade%20to%20This%20Release/from65.aspx

In particular: "Upgrade the CMS database schemas:
SQL Server: Execute the CMS660_AfterInstall.sql script on core, master, web databases."

Comment: @theyetiman We migrated from 6.5. We did not run the provided scripts because they errored out, so we transitioned to a fresh install of 6.6 and then migrated content over.

Comment: I would be interested to hear the progress you made with this, as we've seen this exception in Sitecore 7.5